Gnome videos (Totem) cannot play mp4 video
My attempts to get it to work with gnome video (Totem) fail due to a missing decoder:
$ xdg-open some.mp4

The error message displayed is:
meta/x-gst-fourcc-mett decoder is required to play the file, but is not installed

Clicking "Find in Ubuntu software" in the popup launches gstreamer-codec-install in a background process which never completes.
I can play the video successfully with gst-play-1.0:
$ gst-play-1.0 some.mp4
Press 'k' to see a list of keyboard shortcuts.
Now playing /home/holmanb/Pictures/Brett's Pixel 6a/.trashed-1720475084-PXL_20240608_205818135.TS.mp4
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...     
0:00:00.5 / 0:00:00.5       
Reached end of play list.

I can play the video successfully with ffplay:
ffplay version 6.1.1-3ubuntu5 Copyright (c) 2003-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=3ubuntu5 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --disable-omx --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --disable-sndio --enable-libvpl --disable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-ladspa --enable-libbluray --enable-libjack --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libx264 --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-sdl2 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libjxl --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=3ubuntu5 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --disable-omx --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --disable-sndio --enable-libvpl --disable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-ladspa --enable-libbluray --enable-libjack --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libx264 --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-sdl2 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libjxl --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-static --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc --enable-libsmbclient
  libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102
  libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
  libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100
  libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100
  libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100
  libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'some.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 131072
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    creation_time   : 2024-06-08T20:58:19.000000Z
    location        : +35.7165-105.9799/
    location-eng    : +35.7165-105.9799/
    com.android.manufacturer: Google
    com.android.model: Pixel 6a
    com.android.capture.fps: 30.000000
  Duration: 00:00:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 21413 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Data: none (mett / 0x7474656D), 22 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-06-08T20:58:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : MetaHandle
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-06-08T20:58:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080, 21174 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.87 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-06-08T20:58:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

I'd like to play this video using Gnome video / Totem, but don't how (if it is possible) to make it use the codecs used by gst-play-1.0, ffplay or vlc.
I'm using the latest Ubuntu LTS release 24.04.
Possibly related bugs:
[1] similar scenario: "installer failed, video playback failed" -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/825741
[2] related scenario: "installer failed, video playback succeeded" -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1962123
[3] issue with same codec -> https://forums.opensuse.org/t/codec-x-gst-fourcc-mett-required-to-play-google-mp4/170421/15
[4] I just filed this issue -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/2070804

I never had problem to play, for me the easiest way was to use Smplayer (installed via their officiial page because it is an updated version) and getting all the codecs via apt-repository multiverse.

Use VLC it has its own internal codexs.

A reddit thread pointed me to this bug which had a useful comment:

If I click "cancel" to dismiss the dialog, then totem plays the video just fine.

It didn't appear that this worked, however on reading another comment:

Sometimes if I hit the cancel button in the Totem Dialog box it will play but typically I have to press the pause / play button several times.

If I spam the Play/Pause button enough times after canceling the dialogue window, I can indeed play the video.
